# codeigniter 4 display error "invalid base URL" after reboot Apache

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4, base-url

We are using Codeigniter 4. We restarted Apache (Apache/2.4.37) after found it was suddenly stop working, Site page is working fine before the Apache dead. After restart, all pages displayed same error "You have an empty or invalid base URL. The baseURL value must be set in Config\App.php, or through the .env file." We didn't change any config file setting and confirmed there is baseURL configured in environment file. Could anyone suggest what's problem is it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: did you try to set the baseurl in the Config\App.php instead of the .env file?

Comment: Why has apache stopped working? Are there logs? Is it really running? The question is missing details. In the current state there is not much we can help you with.

Comment: Thanks Vickel, We have different env file and set baseurl in all env files

Comment: Thanks Simon, we have thought the server may be somehow restarted, and the apache need to be restarted manually, but we are figuring out beside Apache any other service need to be started before codeigniter work.